# How to retrieve last command in Terminal that was run from Bash script?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

My bash script runs several commands in separate terminal tabs using `gnome-terminal` such as:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --title "Simulator" -- bash -c "bazel run //package/simulator -- 'server.port=8080' ${config}/sim.toml; bash"
```

However, if I `ctrl+c` this script in the terminal and press the up arrow key, it does not give me the command that was run in the bash script.

How can I run the bash script so that I can press the up arrow key (after `ctrl+c`) in the Terminal and retrieve the last run command from the bash script?

Comment: Would you want the Up arrow key to bring the `bazel run ...` command into the command line? It's not going to happen. Maybe you can manually append this line to `.bash_history` with an `echo` command. See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/issues/2684#note_1904849.